# acces value outside of closure to extend wavesurfer.js lib

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, web-audio-api

I have 2 functions here: load recieves a path to an mp3 and count is the number of tracks being loaded in. When for loop reaches the last track arraybufferList contains an array of 'arraybuffer' of all the songs. This is then passed on to the loadData function which uses an webaudioapi function 'decodeAudioData' to decode all the information and put everything inside an "currentBuffer". However outside of the closure the "currentBuffer" seems to vanish (in my google chrome debugger).

I'm trying to use the wavesurfer.js library and extend it to multiple tracks.

```
load: function (src,count) {

        var my = this;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function () {

            console.log("loading mp3 & putting inside arraybufferList");
            arraybufferList.push(xhr.response); 

            if (arraybufferList.length==count){
                console.log(arraybufferList);
                for (var i=0; i<arraybufferList.length; i++){
                    my.backend.loadData(
                        arraybufferList[i],
                        playList[i].draw.bind(playList[i])
                    );

                    console.log(playList);
                    //playList.push(my);    
                }

                console.log(playList);

            }       
        };

        xhr.open('GET', src, true);

        xhr.send();
    },

    loadData: function (audioData, cb) {
        var my = this;

        this.pause();

        this.ac.decodeAudioData(
            audioData,
            function (buffer) {
                my.currentBuffer = buffer;
                my.lastStart = 0;
                my.lastPause = 0;
                my.startTime = null;
                cb(buffer);

            },
            Error
        );
    },
```

At the beginning for each audio file an object is created where the information from loadData should go into

```
var WaveSurfer = {
    init: function (params) {
        var my = this;

        var backend = WaveSurfer.Audio;

        if (!params.predrawn) {
            backend = WaveSurfer.WebAudio;
        }

        this.backend = Object.create(backend);
        this.backend.init(params);

        this.drawer = Object.create(WaveSurfer.Drawer);
        this.drawer.init(params);

        this.backend.bindUpdate(function () {
            my.onAudioProcess();
        });

        this.bindClick(params.canvas, function (percents) {
            my.playAt(percents);
        });
        playList.push(my);

    },
```

some essential code: ac: new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioCont

Comment: You gave a chunk of irrelevant code. Where is the problem, exactly? `my.currentBuffer = buffer;` - this?

Comment: The problem is that currentBuffer simply disappears outside the fuction (buffer) and I don't not know/understand why or know how to prevent this. I want to put all this data in playList array

Comment: `this.currentBuffer` should be visible on the same level as your methods `load` and `loadData`. Inside `this.ac.decodeAudioData` callback function add a `console.log(my)` and see what it returns.

Comment: if i use console.log the values i find inside the console.log(my) are the ones from the last audio file being uploaded; but if i use a debugger; i find the correct values but they dissapear outside of the callback function

Comment: I would like to extract those values out of the my but var test = Array() = my; doesn't work

Comment: `my` refers to environment inside your objects or functions (btw we name it `self` as it's more descriptive). You use it so you can access methods and properties of the class / function in a closure. But outside the closure you should be able to refer to them as `SomeObj.currentBuffer` and it's the same object that has `load` and `loadData` methods. It's really hard to tell by looking at your code as it's not clear methods of WHAT are they, and how you instantiate that class.